# Parameter implicitly has any type in RN typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have the following code in my RN application.

```
handleTextChange = e => {
  this.setState({ value: e })
}
```

I use TS and this says, "parameter 'e' implicitly has 'any' type".

How can I solve this? How can I set a type to 'e' here?

Comment: What sort of parameter are you expecting there? Change it to the type that you're expecting

Comment: Check [`react-native` typescript definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L1374) for `onChangeText` callback for `TextInput`, it defines parameter as `string` type. In your case if you change `e` to `(e: string)` it should fix the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a type annotation for `e` in cases where it can't be inferred:

```
handleTextChange = (e: Event) => {
  this.setState({ value: e })
}
```

I've used `Event` for the purposes of the example, but you can use whichever type is appropriate.